# curl.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, curl

I installed curl this command (i use Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

When I test simple program using `g++ test.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`g++` shows me:

```
fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

<s>sudo apt-get install curl-devel</s>

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl-dev
```

(will install the default alternative)

OR

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

(the OpenSSL variant)

OR

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

(the gnutls variant)

Comment: Does ubuntu have a `curl-devel` package?  The virtual `libcurl-dev` is provided by several others, e.g. `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, which worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, got my distros mixed up... it should be libcurl-dev, edited the answer

Comment: Thanks i use `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` 
and `g++ test.cpp -L/usr/include/curl/lib -lcurl`

Comment: You don't need `-L/usr/include/curl/lib`, there's probably no such path.

Comment: `yum install libcurl-devel` should be the same with another package manager

Comment: for me as you mentioned earlier ,  "sudo yum install curl-devel" worked for centos

Comment: FWIW, on Ubuntu 20.04 libcurl4-openssl-dev installs to `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h`, and frustratingly - for me at least - `curl-config --cflags` doesn't provide any path

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` worked

Answer (score 49):

To those who use centos and have stumbled upon this post :

```
 $ yum install curl-devel
```

and when compiling your program `example.cpp`, link to the curl library:

```
 $ g++ example.cpp -lcurl -o example
```

"`-o example`" creates the executable `example` instead of the default `a.out`.

The next line runs `example`:

```
 $ ./example
```

Comment: Hello, Ted Lyngmo,
When I install sudo yum curl-devel, it gives the below error message.

Comment: ```Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)                                                                                                                                                                     329  B/s |  14  B     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rhel-7-server-rpms':
  - Status code: 404 for https://hostname/pulp/content/MU/Library/content/dist/rhel/server/7/9/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml```

Comment: ```Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhel-7-server-rpms': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
b```

Comment: May I know how can I solve it

Answer (score 5):

Instead of downloading curl, down libcurl.

curl is just the application, libcurl is what you need for your C++ program

http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/curl

Answer (score 5):

yes please download curl-devel as instructed above.
also don't forget to link to lib curl:

```
-L/path/of/curl/lib/libcurl.a (g++)
```

cheers

Answer (score 3):

If after the installation curl-dev luarocks does not see the headers:

```
find /usr -name 'curl.h'
Example: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl/curl.h

luarocks install lua-cURL CURL_INCDIR=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of view who stumbled on this post after a Google of "`R` `curl` `curl.h no such file or directory`" (first link), who are on `Windows`, and want to install `curl` in `R`, the solution is pretty simple and fast.

- Launch `Rtools Bash` from the `Rtools` folder in the `Windows` `all app` menu.
- Throw `pacman -Syuv` in the command line to make sure you're up-to-date.
- `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-curl` fixes the problem. You can now go back to `R` and install `curl` without any issues. No more `curl.h` missing errors.

Comment: The pacman -S mingw... command worked for me

Answer (score 1):

encountered during building **git** in Centos 8 Stream.

`dnf search libcurl`

`sudo yum install libcurl`

`sudo yum install libcurl-devel`

Now, everything ran fine, and git installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can install libcurl, It can solve the problem. you can find the commands to install it, just check the other answers.

If you still facing the same problem. then what you can do is
You can find the curl.h file in your system, and copy files to the required location

you can find the curl file by

```
find /usr -name 'curl.h'
```

from the above, you'll get the location. copy the curl file from that location to the required location using the cp command

```
cp -r CURL_DIR/curl/ REQUIRED_DIR/curl/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-nss-dev
```