# fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, curl, gcc, mingw-w64

I downloaded the `libcurl` library from https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/
and i'm trying to include and compile it
but I get this error

```
fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
```

even that I put the curl folder in the same directory

the command that I used to compile

```
 x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc try.c -o a.exe -lws2_32 -lcurl
```

So I searched and I found these answers

[curl.h no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471690/curl-h-no-such-file-or-directory) , [Ubuntu - #include <curl/curl.h> no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834233/ubuntu-include-curl-curl-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

so I did

```
sudo apt-get install  libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

but still not working
what to do?

Comment: What you need to have is a `curl` library for the target. It appears you are compiling for Windows target using `mingw`, so you need to cross-compile or download the curl library for Windows and use that library to link with.

Comment: Please include the code you are compiling (the #includes)

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly, `-I.` on the gcc command line may do the trick.

Comment: Also, are you on Linux or are you on Windows? Or are you trying to "cross compile" from Linux _to_ Windows, which is extra-finicky?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it
I just copied the curl directory that I downloaded to `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/`

and when you compile you need to do `-lcurl/curl`

Thanks for your help