# libcurl C++: How to correctly install and use on CentOS 7

Tags: c++, curl, installation, centos7, libcurl

**Goal:**

To correctly install and use `libcurl C++` on `CentOS 7`.

**Current output:**

When I go to compile a program using `libcurl` with the command `g++ somefile.cpp -lcurl -std=c++11 -o somefile`, the following error is received:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ somefile.cpp -lcurl -std=c++11 -o somefile
somefile.cpp:10:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
#include <curl/curl.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

**Details:**

`libcurl` was installed via `sudo yum install libcurl` (and also an attempt with `sudo yum install libcurl4-openssl-dev`). From previous experiences with installing `libcurl` on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`, if I remember correctly I solved a similar issue by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to a `libcurl.so object` as seen below, but this seems to have no effect on `CentOS 7`.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo ldconfig
```

If I run the following command I can see the `libcurl` version which leads me to believe it has been correctly installed:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ curl --version
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.53.1 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.8.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

**Please note:** the following resources have been consulted before deciding to ask this question:

1. https://lynxbee.com/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-curl-curl-h-no-such-file-or-directory-for-ubuntu-linux/
2. [Ubuntu - #include <curl/curl.h> no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834233/ubuntu-include-curl-curl-h-no-such-file-or-directory)
3. [curl.h no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471690/curl-h-no-such-file-or-directory/11471743)
4. [How do I link libcurl to my c++ program in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302282/how-do-i-link-libcurl-to-my-c-program-in-linux)

**Summary question:**

q1. How can this error be solved when trying to compile a `C++` program using `libcurl` on `CentOS 7`?

Comment: Have you installed libcurl-devel?

`The libcurl-devel package includes header files and libraries necessary for
developing programs which use the libcurl library. It contains the API
documentation of the library, too.`

Comment: @Mr.Christer No I hadn't - but I have now and it works. I don't believe I had to do this when I installed on Ubuntu, but I cannot remember. If you would like, please make your comment an answer and I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Also thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to install the **libcurl-devel** package as it contains the headers files you are missing.

> The libcurl-devel package includes header files and libraries
> necessary for developing programs which use the libcurl library. It
> contains the API documentation of the library, too